# Smooth curves on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Assume that there is a parametrized smooth curve $c$ on the manifold $M$, mapping from $[a,b]$ to $M$. Also assume that there is a tangent vector on $M$ in the form $(p,v)$. Tu's text states that it is assumed that the curve $c$ is starting at $p$ if $c(0)=p$. Is there a way to show that $c(0)=p$ in any way? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without any conditions on $c$, how do we know it even passes through $p$?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 If $p$ is some point on $M$, then can we show that a parametrized curve $c$ passes through that point $p$ at $c(0)$. That's my intention

Comment: As long as $M$ is path connected, there will always exist some curve that passes through $p$.  And you can always arrange the curve to passes through $p$ at time $0$, as long as $a\leq 0\leq b$.  On top of that you can always have it so that $c'(0)=v$ for any tangent vector $v$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 i really thought that. But why does the book give an exercise to show it then?

Comment: Are you stating the whole exercise as printed in the book?  I think you are missing some details.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 The exercise asks that if there is a tangent vector $(p,v)$, then show that there is a smooth curve $c$ mapping (a,b) to $M$ such that $c(0)=p$

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I did know from the reading that $c(0)=p$. But I do not know how to show that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is a manifold, then there is some coordinate chart $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow M$ that is a smooth homeomorphism onto its image such that $\phi(0)=p$.  Restrict $\phi$ to a small portion of the $x$-axis that includes $0$.  This will be a smooth curve such that $c(0)=p$.  Further, if you want $c'(0)=v$, you know that $\phi_*:T\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow T_pM$ is surjective.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a tangent vector $v$ at $p$, then $v \in T_p(M)$. Since $M$ is a manifold, there exists a parametrization $\phi: U \rightarrow V$ on a neighborhood $p \in V$ such that $\phi(0) = p$, and $d\phi_0(u) = v$ for some $u \in U$. Consider the line given by $L = \{ x\cdot u|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and consider $L \cap U = \{ x\cdot u | x\in (a,b) \}$. Then the curve $c:(a,b)\rightarrow V\subset M$ given by $c(x) = \phi(x\cdot u)$ is a smooth curve to the manifold with the required tangent vector at the given point.